# Fresh Ubuntu 20.04 install no disk space on / and unable to extend

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, lvm, disk-space-utilization

I have fresh Ubuntu 20.04 with 50GB disk size installed using defaults.

Now I don't have any space left on `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv`.

```
df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               951M     0  951M   0% /dev
tmpfs                              199M  1.2M  198M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   24G   24G     0 100% /
tmpfs                              994M     0  994M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              994M     0  994M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          976M  199M  711M  22% /boot
/dev/loop1                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1988
/dev/loop0                          55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1880
/dev/loop2                          70M   70M     0 100% /snap/lxd/19188
/dev/loop3                          71M   71M     0 100% /snap/lxd/19647
/dev/loop5                          30M   30M     0 100% /snap/snapd/8542
/dev/loop4                          33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11107
/dev/mapper/vg_tor-lvm_tor         5.0T  3.6T  1.2T  76% /mnt/tor
192.168.255.116:/transit            20T   14T  6.9T  66% /mnt/transit
tmpfs                              199M     0  199M   0% /run/user/1000
```

I tried following steps

`sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv`

`sudo resize2fs /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv` **and**

`sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv`

I receive following errors

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Filesystem at /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
old_desc_blocks = 4, new_desc_blocks = 7
resize2fs: Permission denied to resize filesystem
```

**and**

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Filesystem at /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
old_desc_blocks = 4, new_desc_blocks = 7
resize2fs: Permission denied to resize filesystem
```

What am I doing wrong here?

More info about lvms.

**lvdisplay**

```
 --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
  LV Name                ubuntu-lv
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                QYE7ld-fwnU-pm8J-jmag-W4H0-6Pjv-af9OIw
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu-server, 2021-03-13 15:30:58 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                <49.00 GiB
  Current LE             12543
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0
```

**vgdisplay**

```
--- Volume group ---
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <49.00 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              12543
  Alloc PE / Size       12543 / <49.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               h01gbA-v0mW-bPqM-GADT-e7oZ-VBtL-8HtVdt
```

**pvdisplay**

```
 --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda3
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  PV Size               <49.00 GiB / not usable 0
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              12543
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          12543
  PV UUID               k6Xr9q-XSeB-35id-DMOp-bAWH-tVNC-PgCVNW
```

Comment: You may want to check this [Serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/711387/380923). However, since this is a fresh install, why don't you just reinstall and fix the storage sizes?

Comment: @NasirRiley OP does use `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded systemrescure cd https://www.system-rescue.org/ and I executed my previous commands. It worked and now I have full 50GB of disk space.